# PHP preg_replace URL field

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

See this string:

```
$string = "http://www.url.com/?fieldA=123&fieldB=456&fieldC=789";
```

Assuming `"fieldB"` always has a positive non-decimal numerical value (but not necessarily three digits long), what `preg_replace` command do I need to remove it completely, such that the string will then read:

```
$string = "http://www.url.com/?fieldA=123&fieldC=789";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = preg_replace('/&?fieldB=[0-9]+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: @Chad Birch, isn't `\d` faster than `[0-9]`?

Comment: It might be, or it might be slower, depending how it's handled. Either way, that's the kind of optimization that I see on the level of "aren't single quotes faster than double quotes?" It's not really worth worrying about, I just find `[0-9]` easier to read.

Comment: This will fail if fieldB is the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/&fieldB=[0-9]+/', '', $string);
```

Working example code:

```
$string = "http://www.url.com/?fieldA=123&fieldB=456&fieldC=789";
$string = preg_replace('/&fieldB=[0-9]+/', '', $string);
echo $string;

//gives http://www.url.com/?fieldA=123&fieldC=789
```

Comment: @zombat, this looks pretty similar to an answer that was clearly posted before yours.

Comment: When I posted mine, the other ones in the thread all contained incorrect code.

Answer (score 1):

With `preg_replace()`:

```
$url = preg_replace('!&?fieldB=\d+!', '', $string);
```

You should remove the `&` before it as well. Also, don't use `[0-9]`. Use `\d` instead.

That being said, PHP has good native functions for manipulating URLs. Another way to do this:

```
$url = parse_url($string);
parse_str($url['query'], $query);
unset($query['fieldB']);
$url['query'] = http_build_query($query);
$string = http_build_url($url);
```

**Note:** Unfortunately, the [HTTP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php) is not a standard extension so you have to install it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replce('/fieldB=([0-9]+)/', '', $string);
```

Comment: This would leave an extra `&` in the URL.